# While using GRS( Geo Redundancy Storage) as replication in azure its showing error anyone has any idea when it will resolve?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

"Account failover feature is temporarily unavailable due to a service issue that impacts access to the storage account after failover. We are working with priority to address the issue, validate and deploy the fix."

Answer (score 0):

This is currently a known issue and the engineering team is actively working on it. The Fail-over feature will be enabled once we have resolved the issue.
If you have an immediate need to perform account failover for disaster recovery of your production workload, please submit a support ticket with details on your failover scenario. We will work with you to perform the failover from the service backend. For all other non-critical scenarios, we recommend waiting for the customer-managed failover feature to be enabled again.